# Java Version mismatch between control panel and terminal

Tags: java, macos

I recently updated Java on my Mac using the control panel.

on the Control Panel it now shows Java version as Java 8 Update 251

[image]

But, when I check for the Java Version from my Terminal it still shows an older version:

[image]

I already restarted my terminal, restarted my Mac, but it still shows the same.

How do I fix this?

Comment: what does `which java` show? There might be more than one version of Java on your machine. The fact that you have `javac` leads me to believe it's a different version you downloaded for development.

Comment: You can have as many different version simultaneously installed as you want.  On Windows, you'd change your PATH variable to reflect which one is your default.  Or put JAVA_HOME variable in your path and update that one.  I'm not sure how you do this on a mac

Comment: ah interesting, so the java control panel is not the same as the jdk version? how do I update my jdk version?

`which java` tells me: /usr/bin/java

and I only installed one version of java on my system.

Comment: my `JAVA_HOME` says `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- What you see in the Java control panel is the JRE version.
- What you see in the terminal window by using the command, `java -version` is the JDK  version.

You can check all installed version in your system using the following command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Follow the [JDK installation instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html) if you want to install a specific patch of JDK 8.

Comment: Thanks! This helped., I have the latest JDK version installed now.

Answer (score 2):

in terminal take a look on the bash configuration.

```
$ cat .bash_profile | grep java
```

Probably you'll see there that is pointing to old directory.

edit using

```
$ nano .bash_profile
```

and change it to point the the new directory and restart terminal.

Comment: Thanks, but there was no "new directory" to point to. I had to download and install the new version of the JDK which fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone on a Mac doing Java development I would STRONGLY suggest you use SDKMAN to manage your shell settings.  You can bounce between versions in seconds and it uses symbolic links to dynamically FLIP between say Java 1.7 and Java 1.8.

https://sdkman.io/usage

So to install the 'latest' version of Java you would just type 'sdk install java'.

You can also type 'sdk list java' to see all of the versions as well as which you have pulled down as well as what you have current.

I can't say enough good things about it.

Answer (score -1):

JRE Location in Mac This is the Java Version you see in control panel
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin

JDK Location in Mac This is the Java Version you see in terminal
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).